# Is there a way to see how long was the response from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to test out how long is the response from Firebase on different devices. It seems like it takes way longer for Firebase to respond (at least for me) on AVD, than on a real device and I would like to compare those values in ms. For example, I would like to know how long does it take for me to log-in to Firebase authentication on Android Virtual Device and then how long it takes to do that on a real android device? I am coding in Java, if that matters.

Comment: just get timestamp before your call and after the call returns

`Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());`. By calculating the difference should do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check how many `ms` till the response is successful:**

```
long startTime;
long endTime;
long responseTime;


//before you call sign in

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

signIn();



private void signIn(){

mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success
                    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    responseTime = endTime - startTime;
                    Log.d("Time It Takes" , String.valueOf(responseTime));

                }
............
............

}
```